# Assign a DataTable to a DataTable

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable

I want to assign a `DataTable` (**dataTable1**) to another `DataTable` (**dataTable2**) and remove some columns in the latter `DataTable`. For example I have the following code:

```
DataTable dataTable2 = dataTable1;
dataTable2.Columns.Remove("column1");
dataTable2.Columns.Remove("column2");
```

It turns out both `DataTable` (**dataTable1** and **dataTable2**) have the columns removed.  I do not understand why dataTable1 would have **column1** and **column2** removed as well, while I am only removing columns in **dataTable2**.

**[EDITED - with answer]**

Should use `Clone()` AND `ImportRow()` instead of a pointer assignment.

```
DataTable dataTable2 = dataTable1.Clone()
for (int i = 0; i < dataTable1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
   dataTable2.ImportRow(dataTable1.Rows[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because dataTable2 points to the same table as dataTable1.  To resolve this problem, use the DataTable's Clone method to create a new DataTable with the same structure:

```
        DataTable dataTable2  = dataTable1.Clone();  
        dataTable2.Columns.Remove("column1");
        dataTable2.Columns.Remove("column2");
```

Comment: (@)platon, many thanks. Also, it seems Clone() only clone the schema but not the data. So I have to run a loop to import the rows as well. Edited answer to my question.

Comment: @KMC, use the DataTable.Copy method to create a table with the same structure and Data.  In this case, no need to import rows.

Answer (score 0):

datatable is reference type so thats why both of the tables are changing if changes are made in one. and instead of looping through data rows you could either call dataTable1.Copy() to copy data and schema to another datatable.

Answer (score 0):

**datatable.clone() is pass by reference. u have to give it by value.**

`DataTable dataTable2=dataTable1.Copy();
dataTable2.Columns.Remove("column1");
dataTable2.Columns.Remove("column2");`

*Now removing From datatable2 does not effect DataTable1*